# Can bacterial DNA solutions, which include other cellular components, be stored without compromising DNA stability?"

Tags: dna, microbiology, bacteriology, dna-damage

### Question

Can bacterial DNA solutions, which include other cellular components, be stored without compromising DNA stability?"

### Details

I'm using the boiling extraction method to extract **acinetobacter** bacteria's DNA, as following:

> The bacterial deoxynucleic acid (DNA) was extracted by the Boiling
> method of Chen et al., (2020). About 3-5 colonies of each
> Acinetobacter isolate were emulsified in 100 µl of sterile dist.
> water, incubated at 95 °C on a heat block (Thermo Fisher Scientific,
> UK) for 15 min., and centrifuged at 10.000 rpm for 10 min. The
> extracted DNA was stored at -20°C for amplification of the target
> genes using PCR.
> https://nrmj.journals.ekb.eg/article_276319.html

It works as the reading of the spectrophotometer are:

- **dsDNA conc** (microgram/millilitre): 113.26
- **Ratio A260/A280**: 1.77

Today the centrifuge stopped working. To keep to a timeline and to not waste the opportunity of having over night cultures (that were cultured for another purpose) at hand , can I store the suspension after the boiling step, then when the centrifuge device gets fixed, I can go on as usual?

Comment: It would depend on which variant of the method you are using. What's in your lysis buffer?

Comment: No lysis buffer, just 95 Celsius water bath. Tbh i haven't tested the long term stability of the product i get because i haven't done this method for a long time. I have a dummy sample that i'm have been keeping intentionally at room temperature to for 10 days compensate for the time factor, i'm going to measure it.

Comment: Normally this process is done in the presence of a buffer of some sort - it helps keep the DNA stable; i.e. pellet bacteria,  resuspend in lysis buffer, boil... Measuring the concentration is no indication of stability. You need to measure degradation using a gel or similar method. Also what sort of DNA are you after - plasmids are different to chromosomal.

Comment: Chromosomal, sorry I'm a beginner. I got this method from a published article. My downstream purpose is conventional pcr-amplification of partial gene (350 bp)

Comment: The article didn't mention any buffer, but it didn't mention how they stored their DNA,maybe they just extracted it in distilled water then added the buffer after that?

Comment: A link to the protocol would be useful as an edit in the question - unanswerable in this state. Most likely it will depend on the bacterial species too, so would be helpful to add this to the question too.

Comment: Done this part .